# WPF acces uiThread variables with another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, canvas

I'm trying to get the result of this:             Canvas.SetLeft(_canvas.Children[i], Coord);
to my other thread but the problem is it is executed in a for loop so it changes everytime and by using the dispatcher I can't fill a variable

This is what I'm trying to fill the whole code inside a dispatcher but because the loop is too big it crashes and/or starts lagging.

```
            if (YCoord < _canvas.ActualHeight - 1)
        {
            foreach (RectList Item in _rectUseableList)
            {
                if ((int)(YCoord + 1) == (int)Canvas.GetTop(Item.rectangle) && (int)XCoord == (int)Canvas.GetLeft(Item.rectangle))
                {
                    _coords[0] = (int)YCoord;
                    _coords[1] = (int)XCoord;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    _coords[0] = (int)YCoord + 1;
                    _coords[1] = (int)XCoord;
                }
            }
        }
```

Because it is on another thread I can't acces Canvas.gettop is there another way I could acces this?
Note: this loop is executed around 1000 times a second.

Comment: Where are you using `Dispatcher`?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem accruing?

Comment: I will suggest you to better do this loop completely in UI thread. That's the best I can think of. You won't get any benefit using threads in this case.

Comment: I tried doing the loop in the uithread but that cause it to nearly freeze, and I have the whole loop inside the dispatcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you use Dispatcher? I don't see it in your code above.

Anyway... Try to bind Canvas.Top to a property in your view model. You should be able reach that property. If you don't want to modify the value, you don't even need Dispatcher.

Hope it helps!

Comment: How would I reach this model? I'm looping through a list of rectangles and then I'm getting the top from those rectangles.